# ad hoc access to ole db provider 'microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0' has been denied. you must access this provider through a linked server

Tags: sql-server-2017

When trying to import excel file in sql server. the above error occurred .

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Linked Server > Providers and double click on the provider you are using in the OPENROWSET query and check if **"Disallow adhoc access"** is enabled or not as shown below.

[image]

You can also find the value of this option in the Registry under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\INSTANCE NAME \PROVIDERS\SQLNCLI10.  Run regedit and go to above path and find "DisallowAdHocAccess" as shown below.

[image]

We can disable "Disallow adhoc access" from the SSMS provider properties, but it removes the entry in the registry instead of changing the value to zero and we still get the ad hoc access to OLE DB provider has been denied error.

What needs to be done, is this Registry entry needs to be changed to zero from one for this to work for non-sysadmin logins.  So, double click on the entry and change the value to zero and then save the record.

Even though "Disallow adhoc access" is disabled, we need to check the Registry entry for "DisallowAdHocAccess". If the entry is missing enable the option from the provider properties in SSMS and then disable it by changing the value in the Registry to zero.

Comment: when I use sa user then the error does not appear but other sql user gives error

Answer (score 0):

Here is the T-SQL which can be used to enable the usage of open rowset.

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```

After this, he was able to pull data from excel sheet to SQL Server. Well, this was quite a simple solution for a complicated looking problem. If you have alternative suggestions, please do share.